# I can't initialize neither swank nor clojure-jack-in

Tags: emacs, clojure, slime, swank, swank-clojure

I've a problem. I've installed clojure, slime, slime-repl and elein using marmalade. Now I open my project and call elein-swank. I get this:

```
Starting swank..
error in process filter: slime-presentation-init-keymaps: Symbol's function definition is void: slime-define-both-key-bindings
error in process filter: Symbol's function definition is void: slime-define-both-key-bindings
```

and If I try clojure-jack-in I get

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Could not start swank server: That's not a task. Use \"lein help\" to list all tasks.
signal(error ("Could not start swank server: That's not a task. Use \"lein help\" to list all tasks.\n"))
error("Could not start swank server: %s" "That's not a task. Use \"lein help\" to list all tasks.\n")
  clojure-jack-in-sentinel(#<process swank> "exited abnormally with code 1\n")
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what `elein` is, but I think for `clojure-jack-in` you need to install the `swank-clojure` plugin:

```
lein plugin install swank-clojure 1.3.3
```

Comment: nop..it doesn't work neither...I install it but I receive the same message than before

Comment: Make sure you have the latest versions of swank-clojure and leiningen. Type "lein help" on the command line to see if you have a jack-in task. If not, you're missing the swank-clojure part...

Comment: Also call lein deps in the project dir before trying to jack-in. If you're missing some deps, lein will download them, but will output additional line(s) which may confuse clojure-jack-in parsing (it happened to me just yesterday).

Comment: FYI, the install command should be `lein plugin install swank-clojure 1.3.3`.

Answer (score 4):

update: as of 2013, M-x nrepl-jack-in is preferred

---

The jack-in method is the preferred one, but you may also try the old favorite: run

```
$ lein swank
```

from the project's main dir, and then:

```
M-X slime-connect
```

from emacs.  You still need swank-clojure:

```
$ lein plugin install swank-clojure 1.3.3
```

Comment: To be more precise - `clojure-jack-in` and the whole `swank-clojure` support was removed in `clojure-mode` 2.0.0. `nrepl.el` is now the only game in town.

Answer (score 1):

this happened to me when i cloned someone else's clojure project from an older version. their project.clj had:

```
:dev-dependencies [[lein-clojars "0.5.0"]
                   [swank-clojure "1.2.1"]]
```

which is incorrect, i think, if you're using `M-x clojure-jack-in`. removing these lines, running `lein deps` and jacking in worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using lein 2, then try adding  {:user {:plugins [[lein-swank "1.4.4"]] } } to ~/.lein/profiles.clj. see the Plugins section of https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/wiki/Upgrading and https://github.com/technomancy/swank-clojure